# Is there an error on Wikipedia's page on characteristic rotational temperature of HF?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

I am referencing this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotational_temperature

So, I see that $\theta _R = \frac{(h/2\pi)^2}{2Ik_b}$.

I took the value of $I$ from https://cccbdb.nist.gov/mieigen2x.asp.

However, when I do the calculations for $\theta _R$ by plugging in the numbers, I get
$$\theta _R = 46.8324 K$$
not $30.2K$.
Here is my Mathematica snippet
[image]

My question is, has Wikipedia gone wrong, or am I messing this up somewhere?

Answer (score 4):

The units of the inertial constant I are reported in $\pu{amu \cdot Å^2}$. One unified atomic mass unit (or Dalton) is approximately $\pu{1.660e-27 kg}$. Using the correct formula in MATLAB:

```
>> amu=1e-3/6.022e23;
>> h=6.626e-34; kb=1.3806e-23; tr=@(I) ((h/(2*pi))^2)/(2*I*kb*amu*1e-20);
>> tr(0.86)
ans =

 2.820249699307124e+01
```

Using instead $\pu{I= 0.80 amuÅ^2}$ from the [NIST website](https://cccbdb.nist.gov/mieigen1x.asp) returns a value closer to that on the Wikipedia table.

Comment: I realized i made a simple unit conversion error. thank your for your answer!